# Google sheets - range.getColumnIndex() not working?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was using this code: https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/1878143

Everything works for rows:

```
// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range; 
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData_(sheet, options) {
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getFrozenRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getFrozenRows()+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var objects = getObjects_(dataRange.getValues(), normalizeHeaders_(headers));
  if (options.structure == STRUCTURE_HASH) {
    var objectsById = {};
    objects.forEach(function(object) {
      objectsById[object.id] = object;
    });
    return objectsById;
  } else {
    return objects;
  }
}
```

But when I do the following formula I got the following error: `TypeError: range.getColumnIndex is not a function`

```
// getColumnsData iterates column by column in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given column, indexed by its normalized row name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//   - rowHeadersColumnIndex: specifies the column number where the row names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the column immediately left of the range; 
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getColumnsData_(sheet, range, rowHeadersColumnIndex) {
  rowHeadersColumnIndex = rowHeadersColumnIndex || range.getColumnIndex() - 1;
  var headersTmp = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), rowHeadersColumnIndex, range.getNumRows(), 1).getValues();
  var headers = normalizeHeaders_(arrayTranspose_(headersTmp)[0]);
  return getObjects(arrayTranspose_(range.getValues()), headers);
}
```

Comment: I don't see `getLastColumn` in the second code snippet.. Also always provide details on how to use a function. What arguments are you passing here? It is always good to explain what is your goal and which part exactly does not work etc. Also there are functions that you are defining anywhere. What is `normalizeHeaders_`, what is `getObjects` and why you don't use it?

Comment: Woops, sorry that was a typo. My end goal is to create a json from my google sheet where the headers are on the first column.

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to use `getColumn()` instead of `getColumnIndex()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update based on your edited question:**

[getColumnIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-cell#getcolumnindex) **is not** a function of the [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object.

What you want to use instead is:

[getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn)

**Example:**

```
function getColumnsData_(sheet, range, rowHeadersColumnIndex) {
  rowHeadersColumnIndex = rowHeadersColumnIndex || range.getColumn() - 1;
  var headersTmp = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), rowHeadersColumnIndex, range.getNumRows(), 1).getValues();
  var headers = normalizeHeaders_(arrayTranspose_(headersTmp)[0]);
  return getObjects(arrayTranspose_(range.getValues()), headers);
}
```

**Example how to use the function:**

According to explanation of the documentation, you should define the arguments like that:

```
function myFunction(){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const range = sheet.getRange('A1:A5');
  const rowHeadersColumnIndex = 2;
  getColumnsData_(sheet, range, rowHeadersColumnIndex)
}
```

Modify the parameters to your needs.

In order for the above function to work, you need to have defined the other necessary functions: `normalizeHeaders_`, `getObjects` but I assume you have already done this.